# Unpack a string into an expanded string

Tags: python

I am given a string in the following format: `"a{1;4:6}"` and `"a{1;2}b{2:4}"` where the `;` represents two different numbers, and a `:` represents a sequence of numbers. There can be any number of combinations of semicolons and colons within the brace.

I want to expand it such that these are the results of expanding the two examples above:

- `"a{1;4:6}"` = "a1a4a5a6"
- `"a{1;2}b{2:4}" = "a1b2b3b4a2b2b3b4"`

I've never had to deal with something like this before, since I am usually given strings in some sort of ready-made format which is easily parsable. In this case I have to parse the string manually.

My attempt is to split the string manually, over and over again, until you hit a case where there is either a colon or a semicolon, then start building the string from there. This is horribly inefficient, and I would appreciate any thoughts on this approach. Here is essentially what the code looks like (I omitted a lot of it, just to get the point across more quickly):

```
>>> s = "a{1;4:6}"
>>> splitted = s.split("}")
>>> splitted
['a{1;4:6', '']
>>> splitted2 = [s.split("{") for s in splitted]
>>> splitted2
[['a', '1;4:6'], ['']]
>>> splitted3 = [s.split(";") for s in splitted2[0]]
>>> splitted3
[['a'], ['1', '4:6']]

# ... etc, then build up the strings manually once the ranges are figured out.
```

The thinking behind splitting at the close brace at first is that it is guaranteed that a new identifier, with an associated range comes up after it. Where am I going wrong? My approach works for simple strings such as the first example, but it doesn't for the second example. Furthermore it is inefficient. I would be thankful for any input on this problem.

Comment: You might want to look into PyParsing

Comment: You can also do this with some trickery using `eval()` - if you are comfortable using that given the security consideration.  If interested I'll cook up an example.  As your [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) isn't recursive a bit of regex'ing will do the job also and may be a better option.

Comment: Why is there `b2b3b4` between `a1` and `a2`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga hi, it's because I'm trying to mimic the way functions are nested. So anything to the right gets nested in between each unpacking of its left neighbour

Comment: @ialcuaz - I don't have time to knock up an example now but the basic idea (it's a bit of a hack admittedly) is to manipulate the string such that `a{1;2}` becomes a function i.e. `a(1,2)` then using the namespace override input to `eval()` provide a mapping to a function which produces the result.  To support multiple expressions you could replace `}a{` with `} + a{` (using regex to capture the string `a`) then overload the `+` operator to combine the output of the two functions during the evaluation.  Hope that gives you enough to go on, again I think the two answers below are far cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import re

def expand(compressed):

    # 'b{2:4}' -> 'b{2;3;4}' i.e. reduce the problem to just one syntax
    normalized = re.sub(r'(\d+):(\d+)', lambda m: ';'.join(map(str, range(int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2)) + 1))), compressed)

    # 'a{1;2}b{2;3;4}' -> ['a{1;2}', 'b{2;3;4}']
    elements = re.findall(r'[a-z]\{[\d;]+\}', normalized)

    tokens = []

    # ['a{1;2}', 'b{2;3;4}'] -> [['a1', 'a2'], ['b2', 'b3', 'b4']]
    for element in elements:
        match = re.match(r'([a-z])\{([\d;]+)\}', element)

        alphanumerics = []  # match result already guaranteed by re.findall()

        for number in match.group(2).split(';'):
            alphanumerics.append(match.group(1) + number)

        tokens.append(alphanumerics)

    # [['a1', 'a2'], ['b2', 'b3', 'b4']] -> 'a1b2b3b4a2b2b3b4'
    def pack_tokens(tokens):

        current, *rest = tokens

        if not rest:
            return ''.join(current)  # base case

        return ''.join(token + pack_tokens(rest) for token in current)

    return pack_tokens(tokens)

strings = ['a{1;4:6}', 'a{1;2}b{2:4}', 'a{1;2}b{2:4}c{3;6}']

for string in strings:
    print(string, '->', expand(string))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
a{1;4:6} -> a1a4a5a6
a{1;2}b{2:4} -> a1b2b3b4a2b2b3b4
a{1;2}b{2:4}c{3;6} -> a1b2c3c6b3c3c6b4c3c6a2b2c3c6b3c3c6b4c3c6
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried pyparsing for that and IMHO it produced a pretty readable code (took pack_tokens from the previous answer).

```
from pyparsing import nums, Literal, Word, oneOf, Optional, OneOrMore, Group, delimitedList
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters

# transform a '123' to 123
number = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: int(t[0]))

# parses 234:543 ranges
range_ =  number + Literal(':').suppress() + number

# transforms the range x:y to a list [x, x+1, ..., y]
range_.setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: list(range(t[0], t[1]+1)))

# parse the comma delimited list of ranges or individual numbers
range_list = delimitedList(range_|number,",")

# and pack them in a tuple
range_list.setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: tuple(t))

# parses 'a{2,3,4:5}' group
group = Word(letters, max=1) + Literal('{').suppress() + range_list + Literal('}').suppress()

# transform the group parsed as ['a', [2, 4, 5]] to ['a2', 'a4' ...]
group.setParseAction(lambda s, l, t: tuple("%s%d" % (t[0],num) for num in t[1]))

# the full expression is just those group one after another
expression = OneOrMore(group)

def pack_tokens(s, l, tokens):
    current, *rest = tokens
    if not rest:
        return ''.join(current)  # base case
    return ''.join(token + pack_tokens(s, l, rest) for token in current)

expression.setParseAction(pack_tokens)


parsed = expression.parseString('a{1,2,3}')[0]
print(parsed)
parsed = expression.parseString('a{1,3:7}b{1:5}')[0]
print(parsed)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to demonstrate a technique for doing this using `eval` (as @ialcuaz asked in the comments).  Again I wouldn't recommend doing it this way, the other answers are more appropriate.  This technique can be useful when the structure is more complex (i.e. recursive with brackets and so on) when you don't want a full blown parser.

```
import re
import functools

class Group(object):
    def __init__(self, prefix, items):
        self.groups = [[prefix + str(x) for x in items]]

    def __add__(self, other):
        self.groups.extend(other.groups)
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.pack_tokens(self.groups)

    # adapted for Python 2.7 from @cdlane's code
    def pack_tokens(self, tokens):
        current = tokens[:1][0]
        rest = tokens[1:]
        if not rest:
            return ''.join(current)
        return ''.join(token + self.pack_tokens(rest) for token in current)

def createGroup(str, *items):
    return Group(str, items)

def expand(compressed):

    # Replace a{...}b{...} with a{...} + b{...} as we will overload the '+' operator to help during the evaluation
    expr = re.sub(r'(\}\w+\{)', lambda m: '} + ' + m.group(1)[1:-1] + '{', compressed)

    # Expand : range to explicit list of items (from @cdlane's answer)
    expr = re.sub(r'(\d+):(\d+)', lambda m: ';'.join(map(str, range(int(m.group(1)), int(m.group(2)) + 1))), expr)

    # Convert a{x;y;..} to a(x,y, ...) so that it evaluates as a function
    expr = expr.replace('{', '(').replace('}', ')').replace(";", ",")

    # Extract the group prefixes ('a', 'b', ...)
    groupPrefixes = re.findall(ur'(\w+)\([\d,]+\)', expr)

    # Build a namespace mapping functions 'a', 'b', ... to createGroup() capturing the groupName prefix in the closure
    ns = {prefix: functools.partial(createGroup, prefix) for prefix in groupPrefixes}

    # Evaluate the expression using the namespace
    return eval(expr, ns)

tests = ['a{1;4:6}', 'a{1;2}b{2:4}', 'a{1;2}b{2:4}c{3;6}']
for test in tests:
    print(test, '->', expand(test))
```

Produces:

```
('a{1;4:6}', '->', a1a4a5a6)
('a{1;2}b{2:4}', '->', a1b2b3b4a2b2b3b4)
('a{1;2}b{2:4}c{3;6}', '->', a1b2c3c6b3c3c6b4c3c6a2b2c3c6b3c3c6b4c3c6)
```